# How to toggle between 2 forms in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

i am new to Jquery. I am trying to load a HTML with with 2 forms. I need to display only when form when page is loaded but as user clicks the switch button i want it to hide form1 and display form 2 but it hides form1 when button is checked but does not display form2. here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form1 = $('#form1'),
    $form2 = $('#form2'),
    $form2.hide();

  $("#customSwitch1").click(function() {
    if ($form2.is(':visible')) {
      $form1.hide()
      $form2.show()
    } else {
      $form1.show()
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

#customSwitch1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
    <h6>Switch to form2</h6>
  </label>
</div>

<form id='form1' name='form1' method="" action="">
  <input type="text">
</form>

<form id='form2' name='form2' method="" action="">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two issues in your existing code is that you are using `,` instead of `;` to separate your statements, which is resulting in a syntax error in the snippet you provided, and you also need to call `$form2.hide()` in the `else` condition.

That being said, the code can be made more succinct by using `toggle()` to set the state of both forms based on the `checked` property of the checkbox.

Also, you should use CSS to hide the `#form2` element by default to avoid any possibility of a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), and also hook to the `change` event of the checkbox instead of `click` so that your code still works for users who navigate the web using their keyboard.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $form1 = $('#form1');
  let $form2 = $('#form2');

  $("#customSwitch1").on('change', e => {
    $form1.toggle(!e.target.checked);
    $form2.toggle(e.target.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
#customSwitch1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
}

#form2 { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
      <h6>Switch to form2</h6>
    </label>
</div>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="" action="">
  <h3>Form 1</h3>
  <input type="text" placeholder="form 1 value..." />
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="" action="">
  <h3>Form 2</h3>
  <input type="text" placeholder="form 2 value..." />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login-box .nav li').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.login-box .nav li.selected, .login-box form.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('#' + id + ', .login-box form.' + id).addClass('selected');
    $('.login-box form.' + id + ' input').first().focus();
  });
  $('.login-box form .input input').on("focus", function() {
    $(this).parent('.input').addClass('selected');
  }).blur(function() {
    $(this).parent('.input').removeClass('selected');
    if ($(this).val() !== "")
      $(this).parent('.input').addClass('good');
  });
});
```

```css
.login-box,
.login-box .nav,
.login-box .nav li,
.login-box form .input,
.login-box .social-media,
.login-box .social-media li,
.login-box form .input .icon,
.login-box form .input label,
.login-box form .input input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.login-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  background: #29292E;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.login-box .nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-box .nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #141414;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .7);
}

.login-box .nav li.selected,
.login-box .nav li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #006DFF;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  background: none;
}

.login-box .social-media {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.login-box .social-media li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(33.3333% - 12px);
  max-width: 120px;
  background: Red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.login-box .social-media li a {
  display: block;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  height: 40px;
}

.login-box .social-media li a i {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.login-box .social-media li.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  background: rgba(59, 89, 152, .5);
}

.login-box .social-media li.facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
  background: rgba(59, 89, 152, 1);
}

.login-box .social-media li.google {
  background: #CC3333;
  background: rgba(221, 75, 57, .5);
}

.login-box .social-media li.google:hover {
  background: #CC3333;
  background: rgba(221, 75, 57, 1);
}

.login-box .social-media li.twitter {
  background: #1DA1F2;
  background: rgba(29, 161, 242, .5);
}

.login-box .social-media li.twitter:hover {
  background: #1DA1F2;
  background: rgba(29, 161, 2422, 1);
}

.login-box .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.login-box form {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.login-box form.selected {
  display: block;
}

.login-box form .input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.login-box form .input input,
.login-box form .input label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.login-box form .input input {
  line-height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.login-box form .input label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.login-box form .input .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -150px;
}

.login-box form .input .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.login-box form .input .underline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #006DFF;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.login-box form .input.good input,
.login-box form .input.good label,
.login-box form .input.selected input,
.login-box form .input.selected label {
  color: #F0F0F0;
}

.login-box form .input.good label,
.login-box form .input.selected label {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.login-box form .input.good .icon,
.login-box form .input.selected .icon {
  left: 0;
  color: #F0F0F0;
}

.login-box form .input.selected .underline {
  width: 100%;
}

.login-box form .input.good .underline {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
}

.login-box form .input.submit {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.login-box form .input input[type="submit"] {
  color: grey;
  height: 40px;
  background: #141414;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .7);
  padding: 0;
}

.login-box form .input input[type="submit"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 100px 0 #006DFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='login-box'>
  <ul class='nav'>
    <li class='selected' id='login-form'>Login</li>
    <li id='register-form'>Register</li>
  </ul>
  <form class='login-form selected'>
    <span class='title'>Please Enter Your Login Details:<br><br></span>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='log-username'>Username</label>
      <input type='text' name='log-username' id='log-username' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-user-o'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='log-password'>Password</label>
      <input type='password' name='log-password' id='log-password' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input submit'>
      <input type='submit' name='login' id='login' value='Login' disabled />
    </div>
  </form>
  <form class='register-form'>
    <span class='title'>Please Register to Login:<br><br></span>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='reg-username'>Username</label>
      <input type='text' name='reg-username' id='reg-username' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-user-o'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='reg-email'>E-Mail Address</label>
      <input type='email' name='reg-email' id='reg-email' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-envelope-o'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='reg-password'>Password</label>
      <input type='password' name='reg-password' id='reg-password' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input'>
      <label for='reg-conf'>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type='password' name='reg-conf' id='reg-conf' />
      <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i></span>
      <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='input submit'>
      <input type='submit' name='register' id='register' value='Register' disabled />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added placeholders to the form inputs

```js
const $form1 = $('#form1');
const $form2 = $('#form2');

//hide second form by default
$(document).ready(function() {
  $form2.hide();
})

//toggle between form1 & form2
document.querySelector("#customSwitch1").addEventListener("change", () => {
  $form1.toggle()
  $form2.toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
   <h6>Switch to form2</h6>
  </label>
</div>
<form id='form1' name='form1' method="" action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="form1">
</form>
<form id='form2' name='form2' method="" action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="form2">
</form>
```